# astyle, --indent-class and emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

I need a way to reproduce the effects of `--indent-class` switch of `astyle` in emacs c-mode indentation engine.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(){}
  private:
    void bar();
};
```

The way I already came up with, setting up `inclass` to `++` and `access-label` to `-` breaks for the cases where class has no access specifiers:

```
struct Foo
{
    void bar();
};
```

I get double indentation, even though in this case i don't need it.

What am I missing?